# PostgreSQL Join Two Tables by Nearest Date

Tags: postgresql

I have a large single table of sent emails with dates and outcomes and I'd like to be able to match each row with the last time that email was sent and a specific outcome occurred (here that open=1). This needs to be done with PostgreSQL. For example:

**Initial table:**

```
id  | sent_dt       | bounced   | open  `   | clicked | unsubscribe
1   | 2015-01-01    | 1         |      0    | 0       | 0
1   | 2015-01-02    | 0         |      1    | 1       | 0
1   | 2015-01-03    | 0         |      1    | 1       | 0
2   | 2015-01-01    | 0         |      1    | 0       | 0
2   | 2015-01-02    | 1         |      0    | 0       | 0
2   | 2015-01-03    | 0         |      1    | 0       | 0
2   | 2015-01-04    | 0         |      1    | 0       | 1
```

**Result table:**

```
id  | sent_dt       | bounced| open | clicked   | unsubscribe| previous_time
1   | 2015-01-01    | 1      | 0    | 0         | 0          | NULL
1   | 2015-01-02    | 0      | 1    | 1         | 0          | NULL
1   | 2015-01-03    | 0      | 1    | 1         | 0          | 2015-01-02
2   | 2015-01-01    | 0      | 1    | 0         | 0          | NULL
2   | 2015-01-02    | 1      | 0    | 0         | 0          | 2015-01-01
2   | 2015-01-03    | 0      | 1    | 0         | 0          | 2015-01-01
2   | 2015-01-04    | 0      | 1    | 0         | 1          | 2015-01-03
```

I have tried using `Lag` but I don't know how to go about that with the conditional that open needs to equal 1 while still returning all rows. I also tried doing a many to many `Join` on id then finding the minimum `Datediff` but that is going to essentially square the size of my table and takes entirely too long to compute (>7hrs). There are several answers which would work for `SQL` but none that I see work for `PostgreSQL`.

Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: There is a special `FILTER` cause that you can use with window functions like `lag()`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko `FILTER` only for 9.4+ isnt?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to achieve this desired result, connect each one to the one that occurred before if it has open = 1.

```
SELECT t.*,s.sent_dt
FROM
      (SELECT p.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY sent_dt DESC) rnk
      FROM YourTable p) t
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY sent_dt DESC) rnk
      FROM YourTable p) s
ON(t.rnk = s.rnk-1 AND s.open = 1)
```

Comment: If I grab the row number of a table with no conditions and the row number of a table where open=1, they won't exactly line up will they? I think I can possibly use this methodology but I'd have to make some edits I believe. Nvm - I see what you did.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't see the last conditional until I wrote my comment. I'm running it now and will get back on whether it worked. Thanks for the help @Yossi

Comment: It has a slight issue in that it's only matching if we have the `rnk-1` when I need it to pull the next closest row rank. I think you are close with this and the query doesn't take a ridiculous time to run.

Answer (score 0):

First I create a cte `openFilter` for the dates where the mail are open.

Then I join the table mail with those filter and get the dates previous to that email. Finally filter everyone execpt the latest open mail.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b09bc/7)**

```
WITH openFilter as (
    SELECT m."id", m."sent_dt"
    FROM mail m
    WHERE "open" = 1
)
SELECT m."id",
       to_char(m."sent_dt", 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
       "bounced", "open", "clicked", "unsubscribe",
       to_char(o."sent_dt", 'YYYY-MM-DD') previous_time
FROM mail m
LEFT JOIN openFilter o
       ON m."id" = o."id"
      AND m."sent_dt" >  o."sent_dt"     
WHERE o."sent_dt" = (SELECT MAX(t."sent_dt")
                     FROM openFilter t
                     WHERE t."id" = m."id"
                       AND t."sent_dt" < m."sent_dt")
   OR o."sent_dt" IS NULL
```

**Output**

```
| id |    to_char | bounced | open | clicked | unsubscribe | previous_time |
|----|------------|---------|------|---------|-------------|---------------|
|  1 | 2015-01-01 |       1 |    0 |       0 |           0 |        (null) |
|  1 | 2015-01-02 |       0 |    1 |       1 |           0 |        (null) |
|  1 | 2015-01-03 |       0 |    1 |       1 |           0 |    2015-01-02 |
|  2 | 2015-01-01 |       0 |    1 |       0 |           0 |        (null) |
|  2 | 2015-01-02 |       1 |    0 |       0 |           0 |    2015-01-01 |
|  2 | 2015-01-03 |       0 |    1 |       0 |           0 |    2015-01-01 |
|  2 | 2015-01-04 |       0 |    1 |       0 |           1 |    2015-01-03 |
```